# Vector field in notes defined verses full generality?

Tags: vector-bundles, vector-fields

My class notes define a vector field $F$ to be a vector
$$F=(f_1(t),f_2(t),f_3(t)).$$
In actuality, is this actually just the section of a rank $3$ vector bundle on $\Bbb R^1$?

In proper generality, if we have a vector bundle of rank $r$ on a topological space $X$, then any section of this bundle is called a vector field on $X$, is that correct?

Just trying to recall something I'd done in more generality, really loosely, in the past.

---

Additionally, my notes say that $$\frac{dF}{dt}=(\frac{d}{dt}f_1,\frac{d}{dt}f_2,\frac{d}{dt}f_3).$$

What does $\frac{d}{dt}$ correspond to, as a map on sections of a bundle?